# How to get the name of currently connected bluetooth device name in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, ios-bluetooth

I want to get the currently connected Bluetooth name in swift. I have tried
`

```
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
         if central.state == .poweredOn {
             // Bluetooth is enabled,

             // Retrieve a list of connected peripherals

             let connectedPeripherals = central.retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers: [])
             print("Connected device", connectedPeripherals)
             for peripheral in connectedPeripherals {
                 // Check if the peripheral is currently connected
                 if peripheral.state == .connected {
                     // Store the connected peripheral
//                     connectedPeripheral = peripheral
                     // Print the name of the connected peripheral
                     print(peripheral.name ?? "Unknown")
                 }
             }
         }
     }
```

`
but I am getting 'connectedPeripherals' []. I am currently connecting with Bluetooth classic device. What I am doing wrong?[image: I want to get the name "HR-BT-7cabd4 programmatically?] Do I need to pass 'central.retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers: [])' something in that array? I will attach a screenshot.I want to get the name "HR-BT-7cabd4 programmatically? How can I do that ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Bluetooth only provides access to Bluetooth Low Energy peripherals using the GATT profile. You can only get the details for which your app has a connection.

In general, apps do not have visibility of any legacy Bluetooth devices that are connected.

You can get some details of [connected audio devices](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosessionroutedescription)

Comment: In my case, it is a radar. I am getting the name of the radar using 
accessoryList = EAAccessoryManager.shared().connectedAccessories. But that is the name of the radar, I want to get it exactly as shown in the screenshot. Is that possible?